# Error loading Interop.WMPLib Windows MediaPlayer in WPF App

Tags: c#, wpf, com, wmp

```
Error   1   Unknown build error, 'Cannot resolve dependency to 
assembly 'Interop.WMPLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral PublicKeyToken=null'        
because it has not been preloaded. When using the ReflectionOnly APIs, dependent       
assemblies must be pre-loaded or loaded on demand through the  
ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve event. Line 20 Position 14.'
```

Any ideas , do i have to include any more dlls or anything

WPF

```
<Window ...  xmlns:activeXControl="clr-namespace:AxWMPLib;assembly=AxInterop.WMPLib">
<Grid>
     <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="winFormsHost" Grid.Column="1">
         <activeXControl:AxWindowsMediaPlayer x:Name="activeXMediaPlayer"/>
     </WindowsFormsHost>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Window tag purposly snipped

Comment: Have they been added to your references?

Answer (score 0):

You should install WMP Media Player ,if You have already installed ,then uninstall it after restart install new one .It may be possible because

```
  1.COM dll is not registered properly
  2.Because of loading different version of Interop dll(i mean DLL Hell).
  3.Dll not loaded Properly because ofplateform Compatibility 
  or Others.
```